# jQuery onClick PrintScreen & Send Image E-Mail

Tags: jquery, forms, onclick, sendmail, printscreen

I have got an iFrame on my site.  On the site in it, it uses Flash to "build their own cooking range".  Once built it spits out a model number of the cooking range they are looking for.  I want to have a form above the iFrame that could send thier email address (input) and a copy of the iFrame so I can see what model they are inquiring about.

So I'm looking to see if I can have a form that when a submit button is clicked, it will send a PrintScreen image of the page they are looking at, preferably in jQuery.

(Granted I don't have control of the Flash nor website I'm linking in the iFrame.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there is a solution to do this:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

But this uses HTML5 Canvas to make the Screenshot, so it won't work in all browsers & it's currently not supporting all CSS3 properties.

I'm not sure wether this is a good way to do it though. Maybe you should just think about another way to do it.

Comment: Yeah I hear you.  Perhaps I should just make a form and have the user input the model number the iFrame spits out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for Javascript to create a PrintScreen of the user's page. It would be a gross invasion of privacy if website developers could at any moment grab a shot of the user's screen.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot produce a screenshot of the page without a browser plug-in.